# Setting Java properties for `mvn exec:java`

Tags: java, maven

Maven's `exec:java` target runs in the same JVM as Maven itself.

I would like to be able to pass some properties to the `java` binary (in particular, `-ea -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties`) but it is non-obvious how to do this.

Note: I want to pass properties to the JVM, not arguments to the application. Ideally, I would like to be able to specify these in the `pom.xml`, but I realise that is probably unlikely due to the startup of Maven. As a workaround, an `exec:exec` target that sets all the classpaths etc as if I called `exec:java` would be good.

Comment: Same but restricted to CLI solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708846/how-to-pass-systemproperties-when-invoking-execjava-plugin-in-maven

Answer (score 4):

From the [usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>argument1</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
      <systemProperties>
        <systemProperty>
          <key>java.util.logging.config.file</key>
          <value>logging.properties</value>
        </systemProperty>
        ...
      </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
```

The additional JVM options have to be set in env variable MAVEN_OPTS

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-ea
```

Comment: thanks, setting logging through `MAVEN_OPTS` or the `java:exec` configuration doesn't work. This might be to do with the strange startup process that is used by the Java Logger. Basically, the property *must* be defined as soon as the JVM is started. I don't know why `MAVEN_OPTS` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `exec:java` will not work as desired, even if `systemProperties` is used to pass in `java.util.logging.config.file`, as LogManager has already been configured for maven and `exec:java` executes your class in process.

Using `exec:exec` works as expected, and the magic argument `<classpath/>` mirrors `exec:java` experience:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-ea</argument>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <!-- uses dependencies and build directory -->
            <classpath/>
            <argument>-Djava.util.logging.config.file=${basedir}/logging.properties</argument>
            <argument>org.example.Logging/argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

For completness:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL

org.example=FINE
```

For completeness:

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Logging {

    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("org.example");
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {       
        LOGGER.info("Welcome to Logging Example");
        LOGGER.config("Checking java.util.logging.config.file");
        if( System.getProperties().containsKey("java.util.logging.config.file") ){
            File config = new File(System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file"));
            LOGGER.config("java.util.logging.config.file="+config);
        }
        LOGGER.fine("Everything is fine...");
        LOGGER.finer("Everything is finer...");
        LOGGER.finest("Everything is finest...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the command line:

```
call mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.MyFirstTest" -DPROPERTY_FILE="MyPropertyFile"
```

to run your program.

Have a manager class, responsible for reading in the properties.

```
String loggingValue = MyPropertyManager.LOGGING.getPropertyValue();
```

Then, write the MyPropertyManager class to load the properties from the property file.

```
public enum MyPropertyManager {
    LOGGING, OTHERPROPERTY, OTHER;

    public String getPropertyValue() {
        String propertyFile = System.getProperty("PROPERTY_FILE");
        // ... load property file
        Properties loadedProperties = .....
        return properties.get(LOGGING.toString());
    }
}
```

Improve the code so that the properties file is just loaded once.

Comment: at the point when the JVM is started, it's too late to load Java logging properties.