# log4j.properties ignored when using mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm using `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.Class` to run on the command-line. While the program is running, I have some debug output, which I would like to log.

I use `private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("mylogger");` to initialize the logger. I have configured it like this in log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.mylogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.mylogger.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.mylogger.File=logs/mylogger.log
log4j.appender.mylogger.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM
log4j.appender.mylogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mylogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%5p] %C{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.additivity.mylogger=false
```

However, `logger` has the class `org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter` and seems to ignore all settings in `log4j.properties` - it is logging to STDERR with localized warnings and infos.

My relevant maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I get my custom configured logger when using `mvn exec:java`? My log4j.properties configuration works fine when running the rest of the Spring application with Jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK14LoggerAdapter is part of slf4j-jdk14-1.7.21.jar. So my guess is that your classpath contains this jar.

As mvn exec:java and jetty use different class loaders you are only lucky with jetty that he preferred the slf4j-log4j12 over the jdk14 binding.

Also, make sure exec:java **includePluginDependencies** is not set to true (it's false by default) http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html.

In case that after removing the offensive jar your command-line will still want pick the log4.properties file. i.e. typing the following error to the console :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (dao.hsqlmanager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

You can provide the path to the properties file passing the system property **log4j.configuration** to mvn exec:java

[How to pass systemProperties when invoking exec:java plugin in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708846/how-to-pass-systemproperties-when-invoking-execjava-plugin-in-maven)

Comment: try mvn dependency:tree, it's probably transitive

Comment: I found the culprit `slf4j-jdk14` in the `exec-maven-plugin 1.4.0` in `META-INF/maven/plugin.xml`, so the question is, how do I tell `mvn exec:java` not to use `slf4j-jdk14`?

Comment: try includePluginDependencies=false http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html

Comment: <s>Does not help (and is false by default). Perhaps I should just downgrade `exec-maven-plugin`, I know it worked before upgrading</s>.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous comment. In my pom.xml this as accidentally set to true, so my commandline parameter was overwritten and I thought it does not work. Now it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

make sure **includePluginDependencies** is also set to **false** in pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <executable>maven</executable>
  <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
</configuration>
```

remove the dependency of slf4j-api

```
<!--
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
-->
```

from pom.xml.

If it works there is no need to add -Dlog4j.configuration when calling mvn exec:java.