# how to set custom system variable for JVM to access properties file?

Tags: java, jvm, properties-file, system-variable

I need to read `config.properties` file from location that i set with variable `-Dapp.conf=/path/to/config.properties` and set it to a Datasource when i launch my application.
file should be at any location within filesystem.
how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your `properties` file as next:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(System.getProperty("app.conf"))) {
    p.load(reader);
}
```

Once loaded you can use your `properties` instance to set your datasource configuration.

Comment: how to set this variable when i launch my application?
I use maven

Comment: you mean the system property? how to you launch your application with maven ?

Comment: If so check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708846/how-to-pass-systemproperties-when-invoking-execjava-plugin-in-maven

Comment: i launch my app with Jetty from Idea plugin, in the `runner` maven properties, in `Environment variables` i set `-Dapp.conf=/path/to/config.properties`.

Comment: Nicolas, i did as you said and this was exactly what i needed! Thank you!

Comment: How can i insert properties from my `config.properties` into a DataSource defined in `appContext.xml` ?
i'm trying `<property name="driverClassName" value= "${database.driver}"/>` but it doesnt work
i'm trying to load config with this`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
<property name="location" value="file:///#{systemEnvironment['app.conf']}"/>
    </bean>`

Comment: check this https://sethuramanmurali.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/load-properties-file-using-spring-context/