# Java Maven exec:java environment variable on commandline

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to set an environment var on `mvn exec:java` from the commandline?

Something like:

```
mvn exec:java --Dexec.env="env1=foobar"
```

Comment: `exec:java` doesn't fork a new VM, so no, not possible. But `exec:exec` does fork a new VM, so [yes](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#environmentVariables).

Comment: On *NIX, you should be able to do `env1=foobar; mvn exec:java`

Comment: Have a look if one of those does work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708846/how-to-pass-systemproperties-when-invoking-execjava-plugin-in-maven

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is not enough! The environment variable must be exported, to make it visible for the child processes. Thus, the correct syntax is: `export ENV1=foobar; mvn exec:java` or `ENV1=foobar mvn exec:java`. You either need also an `export`, or you have to leave out the "`;`".